# Rdlc Report Error occured in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

```
  With ReportViewer1.LocalReport
     .DataSources.Clear()
     .ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report2.rdlc"
     .ReportPath = "D:\Project\Incentive\Incentive\Report2.rdlc"
     .DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt_tempinc))
     .SetParameters(New ReportParameter("param1", TextBox3.Text))
     .Refresh()
  End With

  With ReportViewer1
     .RefreshReport()
     .Refresh()
  End With
```

this codings are i am used but error occured during in object error message view. how to rectify this problem. thanks for advance.

Comment: When you ask a question after getting an error you should show the entire error. This is not the problem, but according to documentation: [If the ReportPath property has been set, the ReportEmbeddedResource property is ignored.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.reportembeddedresource.aspx) So it seems you are just throwing code at it without really knowing what it does. Check everything. Does `dt_tempinc` have data? Does TextBox3 have a value and it is compatible with the ReportParameer data type?

Comment: I had data to dt_tempinc and textbox value also had. but this error also came

Comment: Well, I still don't know what "this error" is.

Comment: "An error occured during local report processing". this error message viewed